# How to design a RDBMS for big data

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

This might sound a generic question but I have some idea in mind that can get evolve by sharing here.

Our app has several tables of over 10 million records; querying them takes about 40s. We have followed known database design practices like the use of primary keys, indexes etc. We've also tried archiving older rows and table splitting etc but it's still not so impressive.

The application is quite data intensive but I understand that although many sites like banks do have huge data, they still have good performance. I am not an expert in databases; can anyone here point out what I am missing?

There will be some standard techniques like database clustering etc, some which my infrastructure does not allow.

There is a misty idea whether it is possible to store data in a more processed format compared to raw storage? Are there new design practices emerging in database design? Can I migrate to NoSQL easily? Also how good is NoSQL?

Answer (score 7):

Ten million rows is not that much.  Tune your queries on an individual basis.  If you have one query that takes 40 seconds, find out which one it is and fix it.  Using a single column in the where clause that is not indexed can make performance go from .0001 sec to 40 sec.  Most databases have an "explain query" functionality that will tell you how the query is executed.

A *smallish* "big data" problem I recently worked on had 100 billion rows-- 10 TB or so of data, compressed.

If you haven't figured out *why* your queries are slow, you probably shouldn't even be considering non-RDBMS solutions yet.

Comment: i have used cakephp on backend, can this pose restriction on fine tuning queries? also time querying a table is only dependent on that table size or overall size of database have any impact one that

Comment: The size of other tables does not generally affect a query that does not hit them-- lots of concurrent threads working on queries for those other tables *might* affect a query that does not hit them.  But the most important thing is to optimize your queries if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's three tips that are really easy to implement and give you huge performance gains.

1 Make sure you are using inner joins instead of WHERE clause where you can.

For example, write

SELECT 
  LastName, Address 
FROM
  Customer
  INNER JOIN CustomerAddress ON Customer.ID = CustomerAddress.CustomerID

Instead of:

SELECT 
  LastName, Address 
FROM
  Customer, CustomerAddress
WHERE 
  Customer.ID = CustomerAddress.CustomerID

2 Avoid the use of functions in the WHERE clause.

For example,

WHERE left(City,1) = 'M'

will cause an index scan of the whole table (even the rows where City doesn't start with "M")

Instead, use

WHERE City like 'M%'

The same is true for all other functions, like Datediff, Upper, etc.

3 Make sure there is an index on every column you use a WHERE clause on.